# Adding log4j to maven project

Tags: maven, log4j

I am getting Could not publish to the server. java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException exception, when adding log4j dependency to pom.xml
here is dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Everything is OK, when I remove dependency from pom.xml. Can you help me to find the problem?

Comment: Can you put the log in question?

Comment: Please add your full pom!

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance that your webserver already has a log4j library in his classpath. 
And there's probably a conflict between his dependency and yours.
In example, in weblogic you could put something like that :

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
      <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```